# How to programatically move a grid cell in jQuery Gridly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid-layout

We have a [jQuery Gridly](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/) grid and we want any cell to move at the beginning of the grid when clicked. There is no method in the jQuery Gridly documentation which moves grid cells. How can we do this while also keeping the move animation? Is there any jQuery grid plugin that has this ability?